# Can i put both og:image:secure_url and og:image on page for linkedin and facebook

Tags: facebook-like, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

my website is currently running on HTTPS://.  i am leveraging add this for social functionality.

**Problem:** i face following problems on linkedin sharing.

a) Most of time only half of the image comes
b) Some time image does not appear.

**Questions:**

1) Can i put both og:image:secure_url and og:image on page for linkedin and facebook.
   if Yes, what should be the order.
Example:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/ogp.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://secure.example.com/ogp.jpg" />
```

2) Do following are mandatory for linked in and facebook to show images properly.

```
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
```

any solution, but it should work on both linkedin and facebook.

Answer (score 15):

1) Yes, and based on http://ogp.me/#structured, this will tell the crawling service that "the webpage requires HTTPS".

2) These are not required, as FB and LinkedIn will form the correct size regardless.  Remember that LinkedIn [explicitly has minimum requirements](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/setting-display-tags-shares) whereas FB does not.

Answer (score 15):

Here's what I discovered recently with these tags and the latest open graph protocol (June 2019).

1. You have to include the full URL (relative paths don't work)
2. Use `og:image` (not `og:image:secure_url`)
3. `og:image` currently supports secure (`https`) for the `content` value
4. You can rescrape the website and test the functionality with the [Facebook sharing debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)

Hope it helps as I find the documentation hard to follow with these specific details.